# Is Electroencephalography mapping possible?

Tags: medical-physics

EEG measures voltage fluctuations resulting from ionic current within the neurons of the brain. Would it theoretically be possible to draw a 3D model of the brain using these signals if a sufficient number of electrodes were used (ie hundreds) in real time? Or is this only possible with ultrasound/MRI?

I'm unsure of the physics here hence the question.

Comment: Mind giving some more background? What is an electrofrequency signal?

Comment: @flippiefanus By that I mean the electrophysiological signal providing voltage fluctuations resulting from ionic current within the neurons of the brain.

Comment: Add this to your post above @gerardshield.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Thank, I've altered the original quetion to reflect above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not currently a viable option for 3 D resolution according to [EEG Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography):

> Disadvantage: Low spatial resolution on the scalp. fMRI, for example, can directly display areas of the brain that are active, while EEG requires intense interpretation just to hypothesize what areas are activated by a particular response.

[image]

So to obtain 3 D images, well I wouldn't volunteer as it would  seem to be particularly invasive when there are other diagnostic tools available .  It seems to be mostly based around epilepsy treatment.